# fluid text input with floated and variable right button

Tags: html, css

I have a problem similar to this: [CSS: fluid text input with floated-right button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126031/css-fluid-text-input-with-floated-right-button), and I particularly like this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/t7tgJ/3/

However, in my case, different buttons have different text, so I can't use fixed width. Also, the text in the button changes as well (on submit).

Specs:
A text field and a button on one line. The button should `float: right` and the text field should always be `container - button.width - paddings - margins`. How can I accomplish this without Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a play around in JSfiddle. I've gone with a positioning-only version. This might help. It's close but not finished. I hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/t7tgJ/105/

Comment: well the button is over the input =/